# Can't connect to functional mailbox using EWS (AutodiscoverLocalException)

Tags: c#, .net, xml, exchangewebservices

I'm currently trying to get access to a functional mailbox (Exchange) on a different server (A) than my application will be hosted (B).

For some reason, I don't get any access to the functional mailbox, since it keeps returning me `AutodiscoverLocalException`.

```
string url = "https://cas.mailnp.shared.website/EWS/Exchange.asmx";

ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = delegate(
    Object obj,
    X509Certificate certificate,
    X509Chain chain,
    SslPolicyErrors errors ) {
    return true;
};

service = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2007_SP1);
service.Url = new Uri(url);
service.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
service.AutodiscoverUrl("tool@qa.website.com");
```

When I try to access it, it throws the following error:

> Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.AutodiscoverLocalException: The
>   Autodiscover service couldn't be located.
>   at Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Autodiscover.AutodiscoverService.InternalGetLegacyUserSettings[TSettings](String
>   emailAddress, List`1 redirectionEmailAddresses, Int32& currentHop) in
>   \REDMOND\EXCHANGE\BUILD\E15\15.00.0913.015\SOURCES\sources\dev\EwsManagedApi\src\EwsManagedApi\Autodiscover\AutodiscoverService.cs:line
>   626
>
> at Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Autodiscover.AutodiscoverService.GetLegacyUserSettings[TSettings](String
>   emailAddress) in
>   \REDMOND\EXCHANGE\BUILD\E15\15.00.0913.015\SOURCES\sources\dev\EwsManagedApi\src\EwsManagedApi\Autodiscover\AutodiscoverService.cs:line
>   409
>
> at Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Autodiscover.AutodiscoverService.InternalGetLegacyUserSettings(String
>   emailAddress, List1 requestedSettings) in
>   \REDMOND\EXCHANGE\BUILD\E15\15.00.0913.015\SOURCES\sources\dev\EwsManagedApi\src\EwsManagedApi\Autodiscover\AutodiscoverService.cs:line
>   805
>
> at Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Autodiscover.AutodiscoverService.GetUserSettings(String
>   userSmtpAddress, UserSettingName[] userSettingNames) in
>   \REDMOND\EXCHANGE\BUILD\E15\15.00.0913.015\SOURCES\sources\dev\EwsManagedApi\src\EwsManagedApi\Autodiscover\AutodiscoverService.cs:line
>   1663
>
> at Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ExchangeService.GetAutodiscoverUrl(String
>   emailAddress, ExchangeVersion requestedServerVersion,
>   AutodiscoverRedirectionUrlValidationCallback
>   validateRedirectionUrlCallback) in
>   \REDMOND\EXCHANGE\BUILD\E15\15.00.0913.015\SOURCES\sources\dev\EwsManagedApi\src\EwsManagedApi\Core\ExchangeService.cs:line
>   4458
>
> at Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ExchangeService.AutodiscoverUrl(String
>   emailAddress, AutodiscoverRedirectionUrlValidationCallback
>   validateRedirectionUrlCallback) in
>   \REDMOND\EXCHANGE\BUILD\E15\15.00.0913.015\SOURCES\sources\dev\EwsManagedApi\src\EwsManagedApi\Core\ExchangeService.cs:line
>   4416
>
> at Website.App.Factory.Helper.ExchangeWebServiceHelper.CreateConnection()
>   in c:\Users\Joris\Visual
>   Studio\Projects\Website.App\Factory\Helper\ExchangeWebServiceHelper.cs:line
>   39

Also, I didn't try the Trace features yet, because I couldn't get it up and running. A step guide would be very welcome here, but I'd like it if you also thought about the original solution.

Comment: Have you set up autodiscover correctly? Test it with Outlook or some other third party tool. Using AutodiscoverUrl() function will also overwrite the URL property you previously set.

Comment: @kat0r how do you suggest I can test this, by trying to add it in my mailbox?

Comment: If you ctrl-rightclick the Outlook (2013, probably other versions too) tray-icon, there is a "test E-Mail-Autodiscover" thingy.

Comment: If you know the EWSURL which you have already hard coded why are you doing an Autodiscover ? its redundant at that point remark out that line just try to bind to a Mailbox folder

Comment: @kat0r do I need to test this on the server where the functional mailbox can be tested? The mailbox doesn't require a password to connect to, but it can only be added on a specific domain.

Comment: @GlenScales We tried to put the autodiscover in comments, but it doesn't change anything except the error message.

Comment: You need to run this on the machine that you try to run your code. Autodiscover requires changing some stuff on your DNS/Exchange server, and that may work/not work depending on which network you are on.

Comment: "The mailbox doesn't require a password to connect to" - That doesn't sound correct any access to an Exchange Mailbox will require credentials. Whats the error you get if you don't use Autodiscover ? The URL you should use is that of a CAS in the same Exchange Org